# Is there an event I can listen for that will tell when the Flash object was paused?

Tags: actionscript-3

If I pause the entire Flash object (E.G, swfobject.getObjectById('Object').StopPlay();) is there an event that I can capture within Flash to tell me when this has happened?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no special `Event` to listen for that.
But you could use `ExternalInterface` to do that. Just register a javascriptToActionscriptCall and call it from JS:

## AS // swf

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

ExternalInterface.addCallback("sendStopStatusToAS", callStopFromJavaScript);         
    
function callStopFromJavaScript():void {
    trace("SWF stopped by JS");
}
```

## JS

```
swfobject.getObjectById('Object').StopPlay();
swfobject.getObjectById('Object').sendStopStatusToAS();
```

Greetings